# Adding BleshSDK Framework

Tags: xcode, build, cocoapods

I have a mobile application which works on IOS platform and I am trying to add the Blesh Framework to my project.It seems like I did add the framework to the project correctly but I got a problem with building the project.

Here is the exception message:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Blesh", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks for any help or pointers to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags
add this into Debug and Release:

```
$(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC
```

[image: Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags]